# Authenticating a Vuejs frontend with an Express Backend

Tags: express, authentication, cookies, passport.js, express-session

I am looking for some advice on implementing authentication when the client and the server live in separate projects.

### The Server

This API was built as an Express Server. It has routes for CRUD operations with a MySQL database. It also has a user model that utilize `bcrypt` to encrypt passwords. There is no Frontend, in this project.

### The Client

This is a Vue project made with the `vue-cli` and hits the above API to get the data to display.

### The Issue

I need to add authentication. I was thinking I would do this with `express-session`, but I am a little confused with how exactly it works. All of the tutorials I have seen use `express-session` in combination with `passport`. This seems fine, but in all the examples `passport` forwards to a login page that lives on the server. This is usually written in `handlebars` or some other templating framework. I am not sure the best way of implementing since the login page lives in the client project.

### How I thought it worked (Am I missing something?)

I was originally of the impression that for a new user `express-session` would create a token that I would save in the `users` table (maybe generated at login and stored temporarily). Once the user logs in with the correct password this token is passed to the client to be stored as a cookie. When the client wants access to restricted data, it would pass the token as a Authentication header to the server to get permission.

### The Questions

1. Since my projects are separated is `passport` still useful for my use case?
2. Is it secure to create the session cookie on the server and send the token to the client as a response to the client's login POST?
3. Do I need to store the session token in the database?
4. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I have almost the same setup, and I ended up with JWT to generate an access token.

The cycle begins with the user sending his/her email and password to my login endpoint.

In this stage I hash the password using some secret string, fetch the user from database and check if authentication succeed.

After that I generate an access token with an expiring time set, and I expected this access token in all protected routes.

With this approach you can easily implements refresh token to exchange at time to time, saving the refresh token in your database.

This is very simple and Is good to you understand how the process of authentication is done.

[jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)